# When does this commutative non-associative algebra have nilpotent elements?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, nilpotent-groups, universal-property, non-associative-algebras

Consider a non-associative commutative unital algebra of finite dimension where the product is defined by a Cayley table such that elements are generated with real number coefficients
$(a_0, \dotsc, a_n) $
for a basis $\{1, i_1, \dotsc, i_n \}$.

If $a,b,c,d$ are invertible elements of the algebra then $ab = c$ and $ad = c$ implies $b = d$.
(cancellation property)

This implies the answer can be given in the form of a Cayley table for multiplying the finite dimensional basis $\{1, i_1, \dotsc, i_n \}$.

So our algebra is of the form $ a_0 + a_1 i_1 + a_2 i_2 + \dotsb$, addition is as usual and products are defined by a Cayley table relating the basis elements $\{1, i_1, \dotsc, i_n \}$
And clearly the Cayley table is a latin square.

Assume the algebra is also power-associative.

One important extra condition:

Let $T$ be such an Algebra.

Let $x$ be an element of $T$.
Then $y^2 = x$ always has at least one solution $y$ within $T$.

So basically the square root is defined in the algebra.

We also need "Property A"

$$ x * (y * y^{-1}) = x = (x * y) * y^{-1} $$

holds for all invertible elements $x,y$ in the algebra.

( if this property has a name please tell me )

The final condition is that this type of algebra $T$ we seek, is not isomorphic to a tensor product of the complex numbers with another algebra $B$ (taken over the reals).

The dimensions of such an algebra are restricted and must be of the form " extended Mersenne number " +1 or a subset of them.

These extented Mersenne numbers were already discussed before :

---

Consider the subset of odd positive integers defined and constructed as follows by these rules :

A) $1$ is in the set.

B) if $x$ is in the set , then $2x + 1$ is in the set.

C) if $x$ and $y$ are in the set then $xy$ is in the set.

I call them extended Mersenne numbers because rule A and B alone give the Mersenne numbers $2^n - 1$.

And every product of Mersenne numbers must be in the set as well.

So the set or list of extended Mersenne numbers starts like

$$1,3,7,9,15,19,21,27,31,39,43,45,49,55,57,63,79,81,87,91,93,99,...$$

see here :

[Density of extended Mersenne numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440747/density-of-extended-mersenne-numbers)

---

Now the main question is this :

When does such a commutative non-associative algebra have nilpotent elements ??

Does it always have nilpotent elements ?

Or never ? sometimes ?

examples ?

Comment: see also 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4641630/when-does-this-commutative-non-associative-algebra-have-nilpotent-elements

Comment: Why are you posting on MSE and MO simultaneously?

Comment: Additionally, it would be appropriate to give a reference to "That's a long definition I know".

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko I can remove that sentense if you want. But I do not know why it bothers you. It is not pure math ofcourse

Comment: what I would like is for the question to have a bit more structure - definitions, references, motivation - the way it is stated currently, it is all over the place.

Comment: Terminologically, a commutative nonassociative structure satisfying your "property A" is often called "a commutative loop with the inverse property" - probably doing some search for this term in the existing literature you will be able to find some information.

Comment: I edited. Forgot to write invertible.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko I found no references.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko thanks !

Comment: The question still has no clear structure. You are not new on MathOverflow, you surely mist have some ideas of what it means to ask a structured and readable question.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko about " commutative loop with inverse property " , well I have seen inverse property meaning other things and I did not see it in this context ; this is an algebra with 2 operators $+,*$ and zero-divisors so not really a loop. So therefore it might be confusing to say " inverse property " ? But thanks for the advice. I did however find nothing helpful online.

No clear structure ? It has many properties so that is alot structure. Like I said it is a long definition but that is neccessary to avoid trivial noninteresting solutions. Basically trying to construct a nice algebra